# VirtDisk.h QueryChangesVirtualDisk() function return RangeCount as 0

Tags: c++, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, change-tracking, virtual-disk

https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/api/virtdisk/nf-virtdisk-querychangesvirtualdisk?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
DWORD QueryChangesVirtualDisk(
  HANDLE                            VirtualDiskHandle,
  PCWSTR                            ChangeTrackingId,
  ULONG64                           ByteOffset,
  ULONG64                           ByteLength,
  QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG   Flags,
  PQUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_RANGE Ranges,
  PULONG                            RangeCount,
  PULONG64                          ProcessedLength
);
```

I am trying to get difference between two virtual disk or two Resillent Change Tracking ID (RCT)

but `RangeCount` always return as 0

I opened virtual disk file (vhdx) with two enum parameter `VIRTUAL_DISK_ACCESS_GET_INFO`, `OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE`

```
opStatus = OpenVirtualDisk(
        &storageType,
        VirtualDiskPath,
        VIRTUAL_DISK_ACCESS_GET_INFO,
        OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE,
        NULL,
        &vhdHandle ); // output handle
```

then use `QueryChangesVirtualDisk()`

```
opStatus = QueryChangesVirtualDisk(
    vhdHandle,
    ChangeTrackingId,
    0,
    32212254720,
    QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE,
    pRctRanges,
    &rctRangeCnt,
    &processedLength
    );
```

`OpenVirtualDisk()` `QueryChangesVirtualDisk()`

Both function did not return error but in every case `RangeCount` always has a value of 0

There is definitely a difference between virtual disk file and RCT ID

please give me some advice

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <virtdisk.h>

#include "Storage.h"

DWORD QueryChangesVirtualDisk(_In_    LPCWSTR     VirtualDiskPath, _In_    LPCWSTR     ChangeTrackingId)
{
    VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE storageType;
    PGET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO diskInfo;
    ULONG diskInfoSize;
    DWORD opStatus;

    HANDLE vhdHandle;

    QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_RANGE *pRctRanges;
    ULONG                            rctRangeCnt;
    ULONG64                          processedLength;
    UINT                             i;

    vhdHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    diskInfo = NULL;
    diskInfoSize = sizeof(GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO);

    rctRangeCnt = 0L;
    processedLength = 0L;
    pRctRanges = NULL;

    i = 0;

    diskInfo = (PGET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO)malloc(diskInfoSize);
    if (diskInfo == NULL)
    {
        opStatus = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    storageType.DeviceId = VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN;
    storageType.VendorId = VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE_VENDOR_UNKNOWN;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    opStatus = OpenVirtualDisk(
        &storageType,
        VirtualDiskPath,
        VIRTUAL_DISK_ACCESS_GET_INFO,
        OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE,
        NULL,
        &vhdHandle);

    if (opStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"OpenVirtualDisk fail\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    opStatus = QueryChangesVirtualDisk(
        vhdHandle,
        ChangeTrackingId,
        0,
        32212254720,
        QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NONE,
        pRctRanges,
        &rctRangeCnt,
        &processedLength
        );

    wprintf(L"rctRangeCnt : %lu\n", rctRangeCnt);
    wprintf(L"processedLength : %llu\n", processedLength);

    for (i = 0; i < rctRangeCnt; i++)
    {
        wprintf(L"ByteOffset : %lld   ByteLength : %lld\n", pRctRanges[i].ByteOffset, pRctRanges[i].ByteLength);
    }

    if (opStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"QueryChangesVirtualDisk fail\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

Cleanup:

    if (opStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"success\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"error = %u\n", opStatus);
    }

    if (vhdHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(vhdHandle);
    }

    if (diskInfo != NULL)
    {
        free(diskInfo);
    }

    if (pRctRanges != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < rctRangeCnt; i++)
        {
            free(&pRctRanges[i]);
        }
    }

    return opStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass a null-pointer for the `Ranges` argument and zero for `RangeCount`.

For `Ranges` you're supposed to pass a pointer to the first element or an array of `QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_RANGE` elements, and the `RangeCount` should be initialized to the number of elements in that array.

When the `QueryChangesVirtualDisk` function returns it will have modified `RangeCount` to be the number of initialized elements in the `Ranges` array.

From the documentation you linked to, about the `RangeCount` argument:

> On input, the value indicates the number of `QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_RANGE` structures that the array that the `Ranges` parameter points to can hold. On output, the value contains the number of `QUERY_CHANGES_VIRTUAL_DISK_RANGE` structures that the method placed in the array.

In short: The function doesn't create this array for you, you must do it before you call the function.

Comment: next time i should read document more carefully... thank you for helping me

Comment: @TK_WooDong does this work on the base disk of a snapshotted and running VM or did you query the changed blocks on an offline VM ? With a running VM I am getting access denied.. any pointers ?